# C# equivalent of PrivilegedAction

Tags: c#, java

What is C# equivalent of [PrivilegedAction](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/security/PrivilegedAction.html) and [PrivilegedExceptionAction](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/security/PrivilegedExceptionAction.html) class of Java?

Comment: I think you are looking for search term "C# Code access security" or "C# CAS". I.e. [CAS Basics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/33tceax8(v=vs.90).aspx)